# Android Graph with irregular X axis values

Tags: android, graph, plot, androidplot, mpandroidchart

I have tried to see if I can do this on AndroidPlot, HelloCharts and MPAndroidChart.
I have a Weight Management App and want to show a chart of how weight has changed over time.

I've just started looking at this and am falling at the first hurdle of plotting irregular intervals on the X axis.  All of the examples for all of these seem to show linear plotting with every interval on the X axis having a value plotted.

But my users might weigh themselves everyday for a week and then wait a month before the next weight so there should be a linear date scale and weights mapped against it but with many days not having a value to plot.

Am i missing something obvious or is this something that these libraries just don't do and I will have to look at building it from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is simply **fill your x-values array with all days up to the current day, beginning from the first day** the person weighed himself. (this will support one weight entry per day - if a person weighs himself more often than once a day, you can simply take the e.g. highest value and display it in the chart, and only show the others upon clicking the chart entry)

```
ArrayList<String> xvals = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = startingday; i < currentday; i+= oneday) {
    xvals.add(daystring);
}
```

Each entry in this x-values array will represent one day, in indices from 0 to the last day.

If you want to add the weight measurement for the first day, create a new `Entry` with x-index 0 and the weight value. If you want to add the weight measurement for the 10th day, add a new `Entry` with x-index 10 and the weight value.